# What happens when a Quartic Equation has a Quadratic Factor with no roots?

Tags: inequality

I have a question where I need to solve the inequality

$$\frac{4x^2-5x+3}{(x-2)(x+1)} <0$$

after proving that $4x^2-5x+3$ has no roots and is always positive.

However, the question has guiding line saying that since $4x^2-5x+3$ is always positive, the inequality reduces to (Blank), what do I do?

Comment: What is the requirement here? Do you need to complete the blank?

Comment: I need to solve the inequality, but i dont understand the guiding statement 

"since 4x2−5x+3 is always positive, the inequality reduces to (Blank)"

Comment: So for example is there something about a quartic polynomial having a quadratic polynomial without roots as a factor which causes to quartic to also not have roots or something?

Comment: Yes, if a quadratic polynomial has positive leading coefficient (in your case $a=4$) and no roots, then it is always positive. 

Since the numerator is positive, for the fraction to be negative, you will need the denominator to be negative as well.

Answer (score 0):

Note that a positive divided by a positive is positive, while a positive divided by a negative is negative.  You are asking that the whole expression is negative.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the cases (i)$x<-1$,(ii)$x=-1$,(iii)$-1<x<2$,(iv)$x=2$,(v)$x>2$

Answer (score 0):

They mean the inequality simply reduces to $\; (x-2)(x+1)<0$ (and there's a theorem on the sign of a quadratic polynomial which has real roots).